# MySQL xref tables

Tags: mysql

I need some help with xref tables for some reason I am drawing a blank.

I have the following 3 tables

```
+---------------------+
| Products            | 
+---------------------+
| id                  |
| stock_number        |
| size                |
| qty                 | 
+---------------------+

+-------------+
| Category    |
+-------------+
| id          |
| name        |
| description |
| img         |
+-------------+
```

*xref table

```
+--------------+
| category_prod|
+--------------+
| cat_id       |
| prod_id      |
+--------------+
```

With that in mind say I have

- Category: Apples with an ID of 1
- Product: Granny Smith with an ID of 2
- Product: Yellow Delicious with an ID of 5

So I would have in the xref table category_prod:

```
+--------+---------+
| cat_id | prod_id |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 2       |
| 1      | 5       |
+--------+---------+
```

How would i go about writing a query to grab all the products info using the xref table to see what products go under what category.

So basically I would want my output to be All the products from category apples to be displayed with all the fields from that product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the tables:

```
SELECT p.* FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN categry_prod cp ON cp.prod_id=p.id
WHERE cp.cat_id=1;
```

Comment: no problem. welcome to stackoverflow. if you like the answer please consider marking it as the correct answer.